# Export data in datatable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am using datatable plugin for my project. I use "datatable" instead of "Datatable" because I'm using .fnFilter function which throws error in "Datatable". But currently I'm trying to export my table data in different formats like csv, excel, pdf etc. I'm using below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table= $('#testTable').dataTable({ 
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    extend: 'collection',
    text: 'Export',
    buttons: [

      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
  });


  $('#selectField').on('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    table.fnFilter("^"+selectedValue+"$", 4, true);
  });
  $('#selectField1').on('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    table.fnFilter("^"+selectedValue+"$", 3, true);
  });
  $('#selectField2').on('change',function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    table.fnFilter("^"+selectedValue+"$", 5, true); //Exact value, column, reg
  });
});
```

But the option for export buttons are not appearing as buttons. instead it appears as link. Can any one suggest me how can I get the output as expected?

Included files are:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" var="minJS" />
    <script src="${minJS}"></script>
     <spring:url value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" var="minJS1" />
    <script src="${minJS1}"></script>
     <spring:url value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootJS1" />
    <script src="${bootJS1}"></script>
    <spring:url value="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" var="datatable" />
    <script src="${datatable}"></script>
    <spring:url value="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" var="datacss" />
        <link href="${datacss}" rel="stylesheet" /> 
         <spring:url value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="BOOT" />
 <link href="${BOOT}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/BIS.js" var="crunchifyJS" />
    <script src="${crunchifyJS}"></script>
    <spring:url value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" var="buttonJS" />
    <script src="${buttonJS}"></script>
    <spring:url value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js" var="flashJS" />
    <script src="${flashJS}"></script>
    <spring:url value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js" var="zipJS" />
    <script src="${zipJS}"></script>
    <spring:url value="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js" var="pdfJS" />
    <script src="${pdfJS}"></script>
    <spring:url value="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js" var="fontJS" />
    <script src="${fontJS}"></script>
     <spring:url value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js" var="htmJS" />
    <script src="${htmJS}"></script>
     <spring:url value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js" var="printJS" />
    <script src="${printJS}"></script>
       <spring:url value="/resources/a.css" var="crunchifySS" />
 <link href="${crunchifySS}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <spring:url value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" var="ButtonSS" />
 <link href="${buttonSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: What datatables files have you included? Are you including the buttons.html5.js and/or buttons.flash.js?

Comment: Yes. I have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like the correct files are there but it's tough to figure out the problem just with those.  With the app open, I recommend Chrome, open up developer tools (F12) and then click the leftmost button (element selector), click on one of the links (the ones that are supposed to be buttons).  In the dev tools window to the right, it will show you what styles are being applied by what stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorGoodchild. Yes. I already tried this. I will check again and respond to you tomorrow.